# How do I build a QT console app in 64 bit on Mac OSX?

Tags: qt, build-process, 64-bit

I need to build my QT console application as 64 bit.  i.e. x86_64

My config file looks like this:

```
CONFIG += qt console debug x86_64
CONFIG -= app_bundle

HEADERS = HelperClass.h
SOURCES = HelperClass.cpp \
            main.cpp
```

The compile goes fine without issue.  But, when the build gets to the link step, it complains that I don't have the Qt x86_64 architecture.

Excerpt from build:

```
ld: warning in /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning in /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "QIODevice::getChar(char*)", referenced from:
...
```

Do I need to download the Qt source and build the required architecture for this to work?  My install is from the provided binaries for Mac OSX - Qt 4.5.2 on the QT site.  I'm guessing that build does not come with 64bit versions of the libraries.  Am I correct?

Comment: Could you try it without the x86_64 in the config line? That way you would know for sure whether or not it is a 64 bit issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Qt for Open Source C++ development on Mac OS X](http://www.qtsoftware.com/downloads/mac-os-cpp) page it appears that the 32 and 64 bit libraries *should* be included:

> Mac binary package using Cocoa for Mac OS X 10.5 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>   http://get.qtsoftware.com/qt/source/qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-4.5.2.dmg

If you are still having trouble you could try to download the source from the same page:

> http://get.qtsoftware.com/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-src-4.5.2.tar.gz

and configure with:

```
-arch x86_64
```

See http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/developing-on-mac.html#universal-binaries

Note that the link above mentions that if no arch is specified it builds 32bit for the current platform.

Answer (score 1):

The QT SDK does NOT include by default the 64 bit libraries in Mac OS X (I think it is strange but it is that way). For compiling my apps in x86_64 I just download the standalone libraries with Cocoa (32/64 bits) and I install them after the SDK is installed.

Everything works like a charm then.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the libraries using "file":

$ file /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui (for architecture ppc64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library ppc64
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui (for architecture ppc7400):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386

I see the same "ld warning: ... missing required architecture x86_64 in file" errors, so the error message is misleading.